# Why does this Vidyard script change $ to $$?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This script contains: `e.$$=e.$=void` and so typing `$` in the console returns `undefined`.
https://assets.vidyard.com/play/js/player-66763f3813e2458d4b62232f78453b05.js

Vidyard is a web-video technology service. It seems strange that a real business entity is willing to modify an essential part of the jQuery object. `$$` becomes the new jQuery object but this could be entirely incompatible with external scripts that rely on jQuery.

I would bring this up on Vidyard forums but they don't appear to have one.

Comment: Depending on what `e` is a reference to, that may not be the line causing the loss of the `$` variable as a reference to jQuery. Either way, all well-written plugins should depend on `jQuery`, not `$`.

Comment: Actually this has nothing to do with jQuery at all: `e.$=s("querySelector"),e.$$=s("querySelectorAll")`

Comment: "*`$$` becomes the new jQuery object*" - nope, both `.$` and `.$$` become undefined

Comment: I should correct myself; even when overriding the script to be blank, the jQuery object is unavailable.

Answer (score 2):

Good plugins will be written within there own scope as mentioned by Rory. This will look like this.

```
(function($) {
  //your code here
}(jQuery));
```

It's basically a function with parameter $. This function is called immediately with the `jQuery` variable as paramter containing the jQuery object (normally the same as $). You can do the same for your code so you can still use `$` instead of `$$`.

If you got external scripts that rely on `$` you can use the code of them within a scope like this as well.